# how to customize build file locations in Vue Quasar

Tags: vue.js, webpack, quasar-framework

I need to change the default build file locations in a Vue Quasar app.

it is now like this:

[image]

but I need this:

[image]

Comment: I think you might be able to control the path through the appBase of /quasar.conf.js 
check this out: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/quasar-conf-js#property-build

Comment: @bakaDev It is not what I am looking for. I need to have just 2 files in my dist folder.

1. index.html
2. a folder that contains everything except index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been playing with Django and Quasar, and I was looking for something similar, wanted to place index.html in a Django template folder and js/css in static folder. It seems that `build.htmlFilename` in the `quasar.conf.js` configuration file allows for more than just a name but can include path navigation. I've tried the following and it worked fine for me. I got all the assets in the static folder and the index.html in the templates folder.

```js
module.exports = configure(function (ctx) {
    return {
        ...
        build: {
            vueRouterMode: 'hash',
            distDir: '../mainapp/static/mainapp/quasar/', 
            htmlFilename: '../../../templates/mainapp/quasar/index.html', 
            ...
        }
    }
});
```

In your case you might try something like this:

```js
module.exports = configure(function (ctx) {
    return {
        ...
        build: {
            vueRouterMode: 'hash',
            
            distDir: 'everything', 
            htmlFilename: '../index.html', 
            ...
        }
    ...
    }
});
```